# PSObject bug with specific parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that does some simple auditing of group membership on remote servers. The output is as expected except in the case of one group.

There are two parameters two this script, an OU to check in AD and a Group name to check. The OU parameter returns a list of server names, the Group name is the group to return members on. This all works fine except in one case, Backup Operators.

```
param([parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$region,[string]$group)

### Debug flag for viewing output when running the script. 
$DEBUG = 1

$self = $myinvocation.mycommand.name

function cmdopts {
    if ($DEBUG) {
       write-host "$self running with options"
       write-host "Region: $region"
       write-host "Group: $group"
    }
 }

 ### Function to handle custom messages to the user. 
 function usageRegion {
     # Removed for brevity
 }

 function usageGroups {
     # Removed for brevity
 }

 ### Cleanup from previous run of the script.
 function cleanup {
    # Removed for brevity
 }

 #### Function to load powershell modules at runtime
 function loadmod { 
     param([string]$name)
     if ( -not(get-module -name $name)) {
         if (get-module -listavailable| where-object { $_.name -eq $name}) {
             import-module -name $name
             $true
         } else { 
             $false
         }
     } else { 
        $true
     }
  }


 ### Main()
 cmdopts

 #### Validate commandline options
 if ( "cnr","nwr","swr","ner","ser","emr","lar","apr" -notcontains $region ) {
     usageRegion
     exit
 }

 if ( "Administrators","Backup Operators","Event Log Readers","Hyper-V Administrators","Power Users",
"Print Operators","Remote Desktop Users" -notcontains $group) {
    usageGroups
    exit
 } else {
     ### We are creating three files for each run, previous runs need to be cleaned up before we start. 
     cleanup

    ### The ActiveDirectory module is a dependency for this script, we use it to get a list of machine names from AD for the OU.
    if ( loadmod -name "activedirectory" ) {
        write-host "Loading ActiveDirectory powershell module..." -foregroundcolor green
    } else {
        write-host "Sorry, you do not have the ActiveDirectory powershell module installed." -foregroundcolor yellow
        write-host "The script cannot contnue." -foregroundcolor yellow
        exit
    } 

    ### Get the list of servers from AD for the OU specified by the user. 
    get-adcomputer -f * -searchbase "ou=$region,ou=servers,dc=domain,dc=com" | select name | out-file "c:\scripts\ps\$region.srvtmp.txt" -append

    ### We need to fix some format issues with the file before continuing

    # Removed for brevity, cleans up the file output from get-adcomputer and sets variable $srvlist
    $srvlist = gc "c:\scripts\ps\$region.srvlist.txt"

    # Store for the return
    $store = @()

    # Fix the group string for the filename
    $filestring = $group
    $filestring = $filestring.replace(' ', '')
    $filestring = $filestring.tolower()

    foreach ( $srv in $srvlist ) {
        if ( $srv -eq "bustedserver" ) {
        # This box hangs and does not tear down WMI when it can't complete, timeout does not work
            write-host "skipping $srv"
        } else {
            $response = test-connection $srv -count 1 -quiet

            ### This does not work super well, might have to try a custom function
            if ($response -eq $false ) {    
                write-host "$srv was offline during test" -foregroundcolor darkmagenta
            } else {
                 write-host "Checking $group on " -nonewline; write-host $srv -foregroundcolor cyan

                 $groupinfo = new-object PSObject

                 $members = gwmi -computer $srv -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent=`"Win32_Group.Domain='$srv',Name='$group'`"" 

                 $members = $members | sort-object -unique

                 $count = 0
                 if ($members -ne $null) {
                     add-member -inputobject $groupinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "Server" -value $srv
                     add-member -inputobject $groupinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "Group" -value $group

                     foreach ($member in $members) {
                         $count += 1
                         $data = $member.partcomponent -split "\,"
                         $domain = ($data[0] -split "=")[1]
                         $name = ($data[1] -split "=")[1]
                         $line = ("$domain\$name").replace("""","")
                         add-member -inputobject $groupinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "Member $count" -value $line
                     }
                  }

                 if ($DEBUG) {
                    write-host $groupinfo
                 }

                $store += $groupinfo
           }
       }
    }
 }

 #$store | export-csv -path "$HOME\desktop\$region-$filestring-audit.csv" -notype
 $store
```

If I run this script against a group like Administrators, or Remote Desktop Users the output looks like the following.

```
Server: SERVER1
Group: Remote Desktop Users
Member1: GroupName1
Member2: GroupName2
Member3: GroupName3
```

If I run this script against the group Backup Operators, I only get the first group even if there are many. In the debug write-host statement, it will show all of the groups. When printing the store, it only shows the first one. Even if there are two or more, it will alsways print...

```
Server: SERVER1
Group: Backup Operators
Member1: GroupName1
```

Any ideas on why this is broken specifically for 'Backup Operators' and not others would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the FULL script?

Comment: I suspect it's with how your are initializing your `$store` variable but I can't be sure without seeing if it's initialized somewhere else.  It's v. common in PS to have something initialize as a string or array and not return what you think it will.

Comment: Initializing like this $store = @()

Comment: I will add a stripped down version in  a min

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Comment: Added the full script with parts that don't matter stripped out. Usage messages and grabbing from AD, which are known to work.